# SQL query doesn't give the right result

Tags: php, sql

I have a form where people can search the database for four values:
Location, Period, Day and Service. I always do not get the results that I want.

If I use AND, people need to fill in everything. If I use OR I get the complete database. I want to be able to search the database for those one to 4 things. Is there a way how I can do this?

Is there maybe a way to check which fields are filled in, and that the query is automatically changed with the filled in fields?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Zoeken</title>

</head>
<body>
<p><a href="new.php"><img src="add.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a> |   <a href="search.php"><img src="search.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a> | <a  href="search_lijnen.php"><img src="number.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a>  </p>
<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<table>
<tr><td><strong>Locatie: </strong></td><td><input type="text" name="Locatie" value="" /></td> </tr>
<tr><td><strong>Periode: </strong></td><td><input type="text" name="Periode" value="" /></td> </tr>
<tr><td><strong>Dag: </strong></td><td><input type="text" name="Dag" value="" /></td> </tr>
<tr><td><strong>Dienst: </strong></td> <td><input type="text" name="Dienst" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="zoeken" value="Zoeken"></td></tr>
</table>

</div>

 </form> 
 <p><a href="new.php"><img src="add.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a> | <a href="search.php"><img src="search.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a> | <a href="search_lijnen.php"><img src="number.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a> </p>
</body>
</html> 
<?php


if (isset($_POST['zoeken']))
 { 
include('connect-db.php');
$Locatie =  $_POST['Locatie'];
$Periode =  $_POST['Periode'];
$Dag =  $_POST['Dag'];
$Dienst =  $_POST['Dienst'];

// get results from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WMC_DeLijn WHERE Locatie='$Locatie' ANY Periode='$Periode' ANY Dag='$Dag'ANY Dienst='$Dienst' ") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
// display data in table
echo "<h2>Resultaten:</h2><p>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Locatie</th><th>Periode</th><th>Dag</th><th>Dienst</th><th>Delen</th><th>Geleed</th><th>Start 1</th><th>Eind 1</th><th>Start 2</th><th>Eind 2</th><th>Lijnen</th></tr>";


// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Locatie'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Periode'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Dag'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Dienst'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Delen'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Geleed'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Start1'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Eind1'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Start2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Eind2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Lijnen'] . '</td>';
    //Link to edit record
    echo '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="edit.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a></td>';
    // Link to delete record
    echo '<td align="center"><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="delete.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a></td>';
     //Link to Add Event to Google Calendar
    echo '<td align="center"><a href="Add_Event.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="proceed.png" width="20px" height="20px"/></a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
}}
// close table>
echo "</table>"; 

?>
```

Comment: You seem to have SQL injection vulnerabilities here - don't go live without fixing these.

Comment: You seem to be using `ANY` in your SQL syntax. This should be `AND`, I am guessing? One of the clauses also does not have a preceding space, which may cause problems with the query parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either build the query string dynamically, only adding `WHERE` clause statements if the parameter is not falsy, or add conditions in the SQL itself like so: `WHERE (col = ? OR '' = ?) AND (col2 = ? OR '' = ?)`.

Comment: How can this be done dynamically? Seems chinese for the moment to me.

Comment: `$query = "..."; if($foo) { $query += "col = ?"; }` and so on. Just if statements that build up a string.

Comment: My bad, forgot this was PHP. Use a dot for concatenation instead of a plus.

Comment: Oh ok. No probs. I'm trying this out now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to have either a `AND` condition or a `OR` condition like

```
SELECT * FROM WMC_DeLijn 
WHERE Locatie='$Locatie' 
AND Periode='$Periode' 
AND Dag='$Dag' 
AND ienst='$Dienst';
```

(OR)

```
SELECT * FROM WMC_DeLijn 
WHERE Locatie='$Locatie' 
OR Periode='$Periode' 
OR Dag='$Dag' 
OR ienst='$Dienst';
```

Comment: With the  AND condition, all fields need to be filled in, with the OR condition I get to much results. there are about 6000 records in the database.